# Initialization in an extending class

Tags: java, static, initialization, parent

I am confused with initialization in parent class. I need a brief explanation on how this works.

```
public class Bullet extends NextUnit {

    public static int numBullets;

    public Bullet() {
        super();
    }

    public Bullet(GameMain gameMain, AnimInfo animInfo, double x,double y, double xOnMap, double yOnMap,
        double degree, double speed, double speedBackward, double speedRotate, int state) {
        super(gameMain, animInfo, x, y, xOnMap, yOnMap, degree, speed, speedBackward, speedRotate, state);
    }

    // other parts of code are omitted 
}
```

Where would I initialize the numBullets?

Comment: I don't understand the relation to a parent class or inheritance at all. Please clarify what you're asking.

Comment: I am just asking how I would initialize if I want numBullets to equal 5 or any number out there.

Comment: @user6091183, I corrected my answer, look at it

Answer (score 1):

Did you intend to declare it static? A static variable will be shared by all instances. You can simply set its value inline (if it's a constant) or with a one assignment somewhere else.

If it's not meant to be shared among all instances of "bullet" then drop `static` and set it to whatever defaults make sense in each constructor (before or after super). If you need additional arguments for that simply add them.

Are you intending to count the number of `Bullet`s that have been instantiated? Then you just do something like initialize it to 0 and increment by one in both constructors.

Comment: I want to use the variables in other classes too

Comment: That's not what `static` is for. Static means the "same" variable `numBullets` is shared among all instances. Are you thinking of making it public? If so there are better ways to handle that.

Comment: Thanks it turned out that 'static' was the problem

Answer (score 1):

> Where would I initialize the numBullets?

First of all, you should understand that the variable has already initialized by the default value (`0` for `int`). You could use the following ways to initialize your variable:

1. the static initialization block `static { numBullets = 1; }`
2. a static method, e.g. `public static int increaseAndGet() { return ++numBullets; }`
3. directly together with declaration `public static int numBullets = 1;`

The variable `numBullets` is not an *instance* member, it is a *class* variable. The `numBullets` has no relation to the parent class, it's just a part of `Bullet` class. You should use `static` members for interaction with it.

4. together with instance members for clever goals.

---

In your case, I suggest writing the next code snippet:

```
{ updateNumBullets(); }

private static int numBullets;

private static void updateNumBullets() { ++numBullets; }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need to assign default value to **numBullets**, by default it is zero. In case you want it to have another value you can do it using inline assignment like this:

```
public static int numBullets = 43;
```

or using static block like this:

```
public static int numBullets;
static {
  numBullets = 44;
}
```

Comment: It was just a random variable I thought of for this question. Here instead of numBullets I will use maxNumBullets